# Setting a variable in a stored procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin (v 4.5.2) stored procedures, I get an error when I try to set a local variable. The same code works fine in the SQL tab.

I can store a procedure with a standard SQL query and is executes as expected. I can also, in the SQL tab of phpmyadmin, SET a local variable and use that in a query. But when I move the same code with the local variable from the SQL tab into the stored procedure, I get an message that I have an error in my SQL syntax.

The code below works fine in the SQL tab but I cannot save it as a stored procedure.

```
SET @fromdate = CURRENT_DATE;
SELECT
`id`,
`duration_sched`,
`sched_start`,
  @fromdate AS FromDate
FROM
  `appointments`
```

Thinking this may relate to the delimiters, I used the SQL tab again, set the delimiter to '//', and tried the following code, again without success:

```
//
CREATE DEFINER=`caringcompanion`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `testsetup`() 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

SET @fromdate=CURRENT_DATE;
SELECT
  `id`, 
  `duration_sched`,
  `sched_start`,
  @fromdate AS FromDate
FROM `appointments`
END //
```

[image: Delimiter set in SQL tab - where to set in Stored Procedures config?]

Comment: Did you fill in the Delimiter field in PMA's stored procedure screen?

Comment: I've filled in the Delimiter field in the SQL tab at the bottom. I do not see a similar field on the stored procedure screen, which is likely the problem. Can you guide me?

Comment: You need `BEGIN` at the beginning of the procedure.